# Expected number of draws to cover an interval

Tags: probability

**Problem**

Consider an integer number line from 1 to 10, inclusive (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ..., 10).

For each "draw", we draw two integers on the number line with uniform distribution and replacement -- the interval between them, inclusive, is now "covered".

Examples:

- Drawing (2, 5) covers 2-5.
- Drawing (2, 2) covers 2.
- Drawing (2, 5), then (7, 4) covers 2-7.

What is the expected number of draws to cover the whole number line from 1-10? Is this generalizable to the interval 1 through n?

**Attempt**

I can only think of an upper bound; the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) tells us that if, instead of drawing intervals, we drew single numbers, we would expect to cover the line in n*log(n) draws. Naturally this is our upper bound since, on average, we will cover more than one number per draw.

Comment: One way of solving this problem would be with Markov chains. There would be $2^{10} = 1024$ possible states, one for each possible set of integers that are covered. Then find the expected amount of time until absorption.

Answer (score 1):

By linearity of expectation, the answer is $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}_i$$

where $\mathbb{E}_i$ is the expected number of draws needed to cover $i$. Letting $p_i$ be the probability of covering $i$ in a draw, the answer is then $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp_{i}\left(1-p_{i}\right)^{\left(k-1\right)}$$

or equivalently $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p_i}$$

$p_i$ is the probability of the two integers enclosing $i$, which is $$\mathbb{P}(\text{first integer} \le i \cap \text{second integer} \ge i ) + \mathbb{P}(\text{first integer} \ge i \cap \text{second integer} \le i) - \mathbb{P}(\text{first integer} = i \cap \text{second integer} = i)$$

This simplifies to $$2\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n-i+1}{n}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 = \frac{2i(n-i+1) - 1}{n^2}$$

The sum is then $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n^2}{2i(n-i+1)-1} = n\ln(n) + O(n)$$